# Casting a pointer to int and a warning?

Tags: macos, c

I got this warning when building beta release of SageMath 6.1 on OSX 10.9.1, with 64 bit processor:

```
extra.cc:940:30: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

**Can you give an example of the command which can cause this kind of warning?**

The post [here](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0005/) says that there is no way to do it:

```
void *ptr = ...;
int x = (int)ptr;
...
ptr = (void *)x;
```

which is invalid according to the source.

Gcc version

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Are you asking us to fix the code? If so, you want [so], that is off topic here (also impossible to do without seeing the code). If you assume that this is an error specific to your system, please tell us how you are compiling (which compiler, what options etc). Also mention your OS, whether it is 64 or 32bit, your distribution if running Linux, your compiler version  etc etc.

Comment: @terdon I am not asking to fix any code. I am asking a general question about how to handle such a thing generally.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Handle _what_ thing? Buggy C code? This sounds like you have a bug in the code you are compiling, I don't see how we can help.

Comment: @terdon Ok, I will insert here some code snapshot when I understand the problem better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link is correct.  The issue is that neither an `int` nor a pointer has a standard size, but on a 32-bit system they are most likely to both be 32-bits, whereas on a 64-bit system, a pointer is 64-bits wide while an `int` is still likely 32-bits.

> Can you give an example of the command which can cause this kind of warning?

On a 64-bit system using glibc, take an int and cast its value to a pointer:

```
int x;
void *p = (void*)x;
```

Of course, if the issue is that pointers are twice the size of ints, this all by itself isn't a problem, it just throws a warning.  The reason this kind of thing *should* throw a warning is that it *could*, in a "not all by itself" context, indicate a serious mistake.

So, it's not a good programming practice but it does not have to indicate a real error -- e.g., `p += (void*)x` will do the same thing, and this is more obviously likely innocuous, although the cast is unnecessary (and causes the warning).

I notice all kinds of (hopefully) innocent warnings like this when compiling even widely used, well aged software.   You just have to trust that the people who've put it together are aware of this and aren't phased because they are sure there isn't a real issue, just a spurious warning.  They could almost certainly still eliminate them, but GCC is notoriously picky (`suggest YET MORE parentheses...`), and not everyone cares, particularly on portable projects that may be more often built elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, the warnings arised when we changed from "gd" to "libgd" because upstream did it before. I think this kind of warnings can be the result of changing the library. I am reviewing this ticket: http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/15736